# Share GPS location with no Server

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, server

I have been researching about sharing GPS location with someone without server.

**Is it possible to do this?**

I used to develop Android application that can share location with friends, but in that case I had a server to keep the GPS data (Latitude, Longitude) so other mobile can request for JSON data to our server and show data on the Google Map on Mobile. But this time, I don't need a server to keep the GPS data, so **Is there any solution to solve this problem?** I have been considering about to use the data from Google Account, but I don't no how to access the data of Google Account. **Is there any API to access it?** I guessed that Google knew where we are every time we use the Android Mobile so **can we use their data to share our location ?**

Thank you for every suggestions and solutions.

Comment: use *post-it notes* for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is a peer-to-peer arrangement.  Check out: http://openpeer.org/, which is an Open Source project that just released a beta Android SDK.

Comment: interesting, how it works(without any server) when devices are in different carrier grade NATs(as they are if they are using different GSM provider)?

Comment: It's still just TCPIP traffic, and since there is a UTorrent client for Android, that tells me that the carriers aren't blocking P2P traffic (because it would be a constantly evolving battle where no one wins).

Comment: It just becomes a matter of finding/providing a critical mass of seed nodes.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're taking what would otherwise be a trivial project (using a server/repeater), and making it far more complex with P2P, so you would really need either a lot of free-time or a large group of users to help you get it off the ground.

Comment: first i'm not an OP, second with my comments i just wana show that P2P is even worst in this case ... there is no 100% reliable way to perform NAT hole punching (even TCP) for 3G connection ... so, in short, he has to use some server ... that's why my comment under his question is ironical :)

Comment: ... another problem is that for P2P you need seed nodes ... seeds need to keep connections open ... and  keeping conections open on devices prolly would drain their batteries quickly... so still it is better to find free or cheap server and connect to it only when you need it :)

Comment: While I agree with your assessment of server vs. P2P that OP was specific about no servers.  You'll also note one of my comments was "It just becomes a matter of finding/providing a critical mass of seed nodes"